# c# Sqlite 1.0.84.0 vs 1.0.89.0

Tags: c#, sqlite

I've an app in c# and it's working perfect with Sqlite 1.0.84.0 but I should update it to 1.0.89.0.
I replace the dll and some functionalities are not working any more. Im pretty sure that is something related with SQLite.Interop.dll but I don't know how to solve it. Any idea?

Thank you in advanced for the anwer.

Comment: What does "not working anymore" mean? What errors are you getting? How did you update the dlls?

Comment: I've replaced the System.Data.SQLite.dll Reference in the Project & the SQLite.Interop.dll in the \bin\Debug folder.One of the errors is after a Select query - execute reader - Invalid operation Exception {"No current row"}. But with the other version it's working

Comment: And the 'not working anymore' part? Wait - in the bin\Debug? These are temporary files. Whatever you write there will be overwritten the next time you hit "Build"! If you want to add a reference to SQLite.Interop.dll, you need to add it in References. If you want to just copy it, add it to the project as a simple file with a "Copy if newer" action

Comment: But I don't know why it's not possible to add it like a reference.I get an Error Message

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is a mixup on which dll goes where and how it gets copied to the working directory.

Instead of adding references to SQLite manually, you should add it and update it using its [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite/). The package adds the proper SQLite.dll and Interop.dll files for the current SQLite version and bitness (x86 or x64) and ensures the proper Interop dlls are copied to the debug directory (x86 or x64).

SQLite is a native library so you need to have the proper version for the OS you are targetting. System.Data.SQLite is a library built on top of the native dll, which communicates whith it using the Interop dll.

Comment: Just to be sure, this are the folders that I've download:
  1) sqlite-netFx40-static-binary-Win32-2010-1.0.84.0 (Working Perfect)
  2) sqlite-netFx40-static-binary-Win32-2010-1.0.89.0 (I get errors)
I need also to compile it for 64b 
  3) sqlite-netFx40-static-binary-x64-2010-1.0.89.0 (Ive to try it in 64b machines)

For the 32b version updates I've replaced the System.Data.SQLite Reference and I've copied in the app\bin\debug\SQLite.Interop.dll

Do I need something else? Should be done with the nugget package then?

Thank you again for your answer.